# WINRM Enter-Pssession not working on new machine

Tags: winrm

I am trying to enable win rm in mixed domain mode on a new machine.

From another work station, I can connect with the following command:

> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 89.251.114.100 -Credential $mycred

I have ran Enable-PSremoting on the new machine but when I execute the following command, I get:

`Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more info
rmation, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At C:\Users\Dev1\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:93 char:17
+     Enter-PSSession <<<<  -ComputerName 89.251.114.100 -Credential $mycred
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (00.000.000.000:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed`

It is the InvalidArgument that strikes me as odd.

Interestingly, I can execute remote commands with:

> powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted C:\root\deploy.ps1 -inputformat none

Answer (score 2):

Does the user account in your PSCredential object belong to the administrators group of the target machine?

Did you run `winrm quickconfig` on the new machine in an elevated command prompt? It should start the winrm service and create a winrm listener on tcp port 5985 with the corresponding firewall exception. 
You can then try to run `winrs -r:http://<targetmachine>:5985 -u:<targetmachine>\<administrator account> "dir c:\"` and see if it outputs the contents of C:. This shows you that winrm is working correctly.

After that try running Enable-PSRemoting on the target machine again (again in an elevated Powershell prompt).